# AngularJS isolate scope variable value not being passed in the link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following directive, where I want to pass the value of the rating variable from the scope to the link function:

```
providerp01App.directive('changeColor', function(){
  return{
    restrict:'A',
    replace:true,
    scope:{
        rating:'@'
    },
    link:function(scope, element, attrs){
        console.log(scope.rating);
    }//end link function
 }//End return
});//End changeColor Directive
```

The corresponding HTML for this directive is as follows:

```
<div change-color rating="{{provider.Ratings}}">
    //Some code here
</div>
```

The related factory and controller functions are here:

```
var providerp01App = angular.module('providerp01App', []);
providerp01App.factory('providerFactory', function($http){
  var providerFactory={} ;
  providerFactory.getData = function(){
    return $http.get('dataFiles/provider_p01.js');
  }
  return providerFactory;
 });

providerp01App.controller('providerp01Controller', function($scope
, providerFactory){
  $scope.provider; 
  providerFactory.getData().success(function(data){
    $scope.provider=data ; 
  }) ;//End providerFactory.getData()
});//End providerp01Controller
```

And finally, the data looks something like this:

```
{   
"title": "Alexia Nyugen",
"JobDesc": "Nutritionist",
"Rates": "$30/hr",
"Ratings": 4,
}
```

When I look at the Angular de-bugger, I can see that the changeColor directive does indeed have an isolate scope with a rating variable that has a value of 4. However, I don't understand why this value is not being passed into the link function. It doesn't produce any error message, just no values are shown. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try defining `scope:{ rating:'='}`

Comment: if yes put a watch on `scope.rating` inside the link function and check if it is undefined.if it is not undefined call your function

Comment: The problem here is that the `link` function is only called once so your `console.log` runs before the `getData` promise is resolved. See this example for why it probably doesn't matter ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/TFo3YFcOyzaLotczwBzH?p=preview

Comment: This seems to be the reason, as it takes a couple of refreshes before I can see the rating=4 value. Thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If rating does not change, I suggest simply putting

```
scope.ratings = attrs.rating
```

in the body of your link function. Otherwise, I would use $observe in the link function

```
attrs.$observe('rating', function(value) {
    //implement rating-dependent behavior here
}
```